# Free Datasource for DTM in Northwest Russia (Karelia)

Tags: geospatial, russia

I'm looking for a Digital Terrain Model in the Karelia region (Russia) with a spat. resolution about 30m. (Also Contour Lines would be ok)

I read an article about the "RuDTM2014" https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309312124_RuDTM2014_New_digital_terrain_model_for_Russia_and_its_effect_on_the_prediction_of_mean_gravity_anomalies ,but there's no information about where to find the data. I checked out ALOS World 3D Data but this has too much noise in that particular area and the ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model has a bad quality. Using this datasource: http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html#others gives only a resolution of approx. 40m.

Are there data sources in Russia which provide this data for free?